# How to add tooltip to the placeholder of an input tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I would like to create something like this:

[image]

The placeholder needs to be "Event Terms" plus a question mark icon. When the user hover over the question mark, the tooltip will appear.

I don't think a placeholder can contain a question mark icon with tooltip. I'm thinking about adding the text and icon in a separate div, which can then be displayed inside the input area.

Is this the right approach? Please let me know if you have a better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done so

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #ccc;
}
.placeholder b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input:focus + span,
input:valid + span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="placeholder">Text<b title="Lorem ipsum">?</b></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use `:before` or `:after` to achieve something like you except.
And I would recommend wrap inputs to `label` instead of `div`.

```css
label.myLabel {
  position: relative;
}
.myLabel > input[type=text] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
.tag {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
}
.tag:before {
  content: "text will show up";
  display: none;
  width: 120px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
}
.tag:hover:before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="myLabel">
  <input type="text"/>
  <div class="tag">?</div>
</label>
```

Or you can set pop-up text to attribute for your input or label and read & set it as stile of `tag` element.

Answer (score 0):

In angular material one can utilise the mat-label property to obtain placeholder.

within mat-form-field have the attribute mat-label containing placeholder as shown below:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>
    <span matTooltip="The display value for tooltip.">
      Tooltip Name
    </span>
  </mat-label>
      <input matInput required maxlength="160">
 </mat-form-field>
```

also in css component add:

```
mat-label {
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```